# Raspbian Jessie Wi-Fi doesn't work with multiple IPs on same network

Tags: raspbian, wifi, static-ip

I would like to use two different static IP addresses for the same network with the same Wi-Fi dongle. I read in different forums that it's better to use `/etc/network/interfaces` instead of `dhcpcd.conf` for that purpose.
So I changed the `/etc/network/interfaces` that way:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.60
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.10
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
auto wlan0:0
allow-hotplug wlan0:0
iface wlan0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.61
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The issue now is that for the most of the time I can't ping any member of the network. During the first 10 seconds, everything works fine and then I mostly don't get any connection.

`ifconfig` shows the following:

```
lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX packets:1237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
          RX bytes:100748 (98.3 KiB)  TX bytes:100748 (98.3 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:a2:4b:72  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.60  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ba27:ebff:fea2:4b72/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:15498 errors:0 dropped:10634 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX bytes:5910381 (5.6 MiB)  TX bytes:722284 (705.3 KiB)

wlan0:0   Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:a2:4b:72  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.61  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
```

and route -ne has the following output:

```
 Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags   MSS Fenster irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.10    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

I also stoped dhcpcd, the IPs aren't in the dhcp pool of the router and with one static ip everything works fine. 
Does anyone have any clue what I did wrong?

Comment: Is your wifi router running a DHCP server?  And if so, does the dynamic address pool include the addresses you've assigned as static on the client?

Comment: yes, but the range of the address pool is form 192.168.0.220-249

Comment: So, the DHCP shouldn't be a problem... if you comment out the 2nd configuration, does the Wifi work as expected?

Comment: Yes with one ip everything works fine

Comment: This is a good question, but it seems more Linux related than Pi specific.  If you don't get much traction here, consider moving it to the Linux SE.

Comment: Dose it matter that there's no gateway addr in the wlan0:0 config?

Comment: according to the instructuions i have read, there shouldn't be any gateway at wlan0:0, they explicit said that. But i can try it tommorow

Comment: ok on linux se i got the answer:https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403970/260092

Comment: Answered on U&L -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403970/82256